# Why don't I get a HTTP status code from Firebase Server? Swift - Vapor server

Tags: swift3, vapor

I am writing to Firebase Database from a Vapor server using the Firebase REST API. Why don't I get a *Status code* in the header received? This would enable me to check if the write was successful or not.

> headerReceived items line 83 in
>   extensionPutRequestToUsersClaimBookingCleaner are
>
> ([Connection: "keep-alive",  Cache-Control: "no-cache",  Server:
>   "nginx",  Date: "Sun,  27 Aug 2017 21:47:25 GMT",  Content-Type:
>   "application/json;  charset=utf-8",  Content-Length: "1027", 
>   Strict-Transport-Security:  "max-age=31556926;  includeSubDomains; 
>   preload",  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"])

Comment: What do you mean? You dont get a status code when inspecting in the network tab of dev tools?

Comment: @Rienk , If I make the request using Postman, it shows status 201. However, when I make the request using the Vapor client, in the header received from Firebase server, I don't get a Status code key: value. There is no key:value with Status: XXXXX received from Firebase in the header of the response. Please see the a copy of the header received from Firebase upon a successful PUT

Comment: Are you using Vapor's `client` to contact your Firebase server?

Comment: @tobygriffin   yes, I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response's status code is returned in the `status` property rather than the `headers` property.

```
guard response.status == .created else {
  // not a 201 response
}
```

Comment: Could you please advise if the way in which I create my JSON object is correct? I keep getting an error when I send the object to Firebase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100421 . Thank you